# ARToolkit, UIImagePickerController & cameraOverlayView: How to take a picture?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality

I am developing an Augmented Reality app for iPhone with ARToolkit. Now I want to include its functionality in a main app, with a button which throws an 'AR View', in order to be able to take a picture with the 3D model on it.

I am using **UIImagePickerController** with **cameraOverlayView** to add the ARViewController view to the camera view, as an overlay, but it does not show it. Here it is the code:

```
-(IBAction)Switch2AR:(id)sender{

ARController = [[ARViewController alloc] init];
[ARController loadView];

UIImagePickerController *picker  = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;


if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
}
else {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;

picker.cameraOverlayView = ARController.view;


//[ARController.view addSubview: picker.view];
//[picker.view addSubview: ARController.view];

//[picker viewWillAppear:YES];
//[picker viewDidAppear:YES];
//[ARController viewWillAppear:YES];
//[ARController viewDidAppear:YES];


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[ARController release];

}
```

I also tried to add the **UIImagePickerController** view as a subview of the **ARViewController view**, but does not work since the camera modal view 'hides' the AR view. Also ARViewController view as **UIImagePickerController** subview.

The problem is that I cannot overlay my ARView and the camera view in any way I tried

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

to

```
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

and it should work.